# Using PyCharm on a remote server

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-access

I never used a server before (only my local machine), and recently I was given a server with Python files on it. I was also given SSH key and a password.
I'm trying to connect PyCharm to the server from my local machine so that I can write code on my local machine, upload the code to the server, and use code from existing files on the server.

The only website I found is [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/create-ssh-configurations.html), and I followed the instructions to create an SSH interpreter, but I'm not sure what to do next (in order to see the files, write files to the server, etc,).

Comment: If you can't get it working, Visual Studio Code also has remote capabilities. The linter isn't near as good as Pycharm's (actually, it's quite bad) but it works.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yea I was actually told about visual Studio by my colleague in the lab, but since I've been using PyCharm since I started I thought that it might be easier to keep using it. Though, I've been trying to figure out this remote thing for half a day now, so I'm not so sure anymore

Comment: PyCharm can do this well, do not switch to visual studio, but follow this guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html and select sftp, after you can just run the code over an ssh session on the remote server. If you want to do remote debugging, it's possible but much more complicated to understand.

Comment: @AnthonyPerot any idea what to do in the "Web server URL"? I was only given an SSH key and password

Comment: omit this, it's only in case it's a webserver,

Comment: @AnthonyPerot okay I finished the guide and I still don't see the files. Any tips?